# Normal to the hypersurface

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, vectors, causality

I have a given metric and I want to choose a spacelike hypersurface and find the normal to that hypersurface. I know that if the hypersurface is spacelike, then the normal is timelike.
The given metric is $$(1-2m/r) du^2 -2 du dr -r^2 d\theta^2 - r^2\sin^2\theta d\phi^2 + (4 m a/r) \sin^2\theta d\phi du + 2 a \sin^2\theta dr d\phi .$$
If I choose the hypersurface r = Constant = R, then my induced metric on the hypersurface will be $$(1-2m/R) du^2  -R^2 d\theta^2 - R^2\sin^2\theta d\phi^2 + (4 m a/R) \sin^2\theta d\phi du  .$$ Can anyone tell me how to find normal to this hypersurface?

Comment: A vector $n^\mu$ is timelike if $n^\mu n_\mu > 0$ and it is spacelike if $n^\mu n_\mu < 0$.

Comment: Does above definition depend on metric signature?

Comment: It does. I am using the signature used in your question.

Comment: Thanks. I knew this definition but was getting confused every time for spacelike, whether it will be +1 or -1 as I didn't know it depends on the metric signature. Now it is clear to me.

Comment: You can take tangent vectors $(1,0,0,0)$, $(0,0,1,0)$, and $(0,0,0,1)$. Can you find a vector that is orthogonal to all three?

Comment: A vector orthogonal to all these and hence normal vector will be (0,1,0,0) I guess. But my doubt is whether to take it as contravariant or covariant. i.e whether n$^\mu$ = (0,1,0,0) or n$_\mu$ = (0,1,0,0)